# Cannot retrieve from the special character at the end of the string as Terminator with JSON using regex

Tags: python, json, regex, dictionary

Terminator of this Json string by `!!` but not at the last record so that i cannot retrieve all corresponding records by `({.*?}!!)` when i using `({.*?})` i can retrieve all but no with completed values.

**JSON**

```
x = {'d':'AAAAA@5##{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}!!AAAAA@6##{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}!!AAAAA@7##{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}'}
```

**Nice formatting**

```
x = {'d':'AAAAA@5##{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}
     !!AAAAA@6##{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}
     !!AAAAA@7##{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}'}
```

**Python Code**

```
re.findall(r"(AAAAA@\d+##)({.*?})", x['d'])
```

**Result**

```
 [('AAAAA@5##', '{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003}'),
 ('AAAAA@6##', '{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003}'),
 ('AAAAA@7##', '{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003}')]
```

**When I using following code**

```
re.findall(r"(AAAAA@\d+##)({.*?}!!)", x['d'])
```

**2nd Result**

```
 [('AAAAA@5##',
 '{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 
   1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}!!'),
 ('AAAAA@6##',
 '{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 
 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}!!')]
```

*Just show two records only*

**My Expected Result**

```
  [('AAAAA@5##',
  '{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 
   1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}!!'),
 ('AAAAA@6##',
 '{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 
 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}!!'),
   ('AAAAA@7##',
 '{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 
 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

x = {'d':'AAAAA@5##{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}!!AAAAA@6##{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}!!AAAAA@7##{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}'}

# simply split the json by !! using str.split() method
# then find the groups
# group 1 --> (.*##)
# group 2--> ({.*})

[re.findall(r'(.*##)({.*})', i)[0] for i in x['d'].split('!!')]
```

```
[('AAAAA@5##',
  '{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}'),
 ('AAAAA@6##',
  '{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}'),
 ('AAAAA@7##',
  '{"pp-0":[{"pp-1": 1000, "pp-3": 1003},{"pp-4": 1004, "pp-7": 1007},{"pp-8": 1008, "pp-11": 1011},{"pp-12": 1012,"pp-17": 1015}],"pp-17": 1015,"pp-17": 1015}')]
```

or use regex completely

```py
re.findall(r'([^!]+##)({[^!]+})', x['d'])
```

Find regex explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/4HYLDJ/1)

Comment: dear, would you mind to add more explanation, thanks !

Comment: Added, please check